# Get Mouse Position or Element Position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a tooltip plugin with the following options:

1. Mouse = True|False. Tooltip position relative to Mouse or Element;
2. Static = True|False. Follow mouse when option Mouse = true.

I have a JSFiddle example in: http://jsfiddle.net/mdmoura/RPUX6/

THE PROBLEM:

When I place the mouse over the last tooltips of the list the position is wrong.

This happens every time I have scrolled the page ... I have no idea why.

The part of the code which sets the position is:

```
$(this).each(function (e) {
  // SOME CODE  

  $this.mouseenter(function (e) {

    var $tooltip =
      $("<div>")
      .attr("class", options.class)
      .html(options.content !== '' ? (typeof options.content === 'string' ? options.content : options.content($this, $tooltip)) : tooltip.title)
      .appendTo('body');

    $this.attr('title', '');

    var position = [0, 0];

    if (options.mouse) {
      position = [e.clientX + options.offset[0], e.clientY + options.offset[1]];
    } else {
      var coordinates = $this[0].getBoundingClientRect();       
      position = [
        (function () {
          if (options.offset[0] < 0)
            return coordinates.left - Math.abs(options.offset[0]) - $tooltip.outerWidth();
          else if (options.offset[0] === 0)
            return coordinates.left - (($tooltip.outerWidth() - $this.outerWidth()) / 2);
          else
            return coordinates.left + $this.outerWidth() + options.offset[0];

        })(),
        (function () {
          if (options.offset[1] < 0)
            return coordinates.top - Math.abs(options.offset[1]) - $tooltip.outerHeight();
          else if (options.offset[1] === 0)
            return coordinates.top - (($tooltip.outerHeight() - $this.outerHeight()) / 2);
          else
            return coordinates.top + $this.outerHeight() + options.offset[1];

        })()
      ];
    }

    $tooltip.css({ left: position[0] + 'px', top: position[1] + 'px' });
```

You can also see the code and the demo in http://jsfiddle.net/mdmoura/RPUX6/.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and [scrollLeft](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) of the window.

Basic idea:

```
var win = $(window);
$tooltip.css( {
    left: position[0] + win.scrollLeft() + 'px', 
    top: position[1] + win.scrollTop() + 'px' 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add scrollTop by

```
document.body.scrollTop
```

And you will be good to go..

In your code make these changes

> function () {
>             if (options.offset[1] < 0)
>               return coordinates.top - Math.abs(options.offset[1]) - $tooltip.outerHeight()**+document.body.scrollTop**;
>             else if (options.offset[1] === 0)
>               return coordinates.top - (($tooltip.outerHeight() - $this.outerHeight()) / 2)**+document.body.scrollTop**;
>             else
>               return coordinates.top + $this.outerHeight() + options.offset[1]**+document.body.scrollTop**;
>
> })